# how to set comment to label using command line

Tags: command-line, visual-sourcesafe

I can set a label for a project in SourceSafe using label command.

If you look at dialog which set the label, there are two comments fields: 
label comment and comment.

How can I set them in label command and prevent batch file asking them?

Comment: Could you post your code so that we can see *specifically* what the problem is? At the moment it's quite unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I do not try this, but in according with documentation it should be

```
ss Label $/ -LLabelName -C"Comment Text" -I-
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d9sd5y2(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: My question was not how to set label comment. If you look at label in SourceSafe there are two text boxes for comments. One has name "Label comment" and can be set using command line. Another has name "Comment". Question is can we set this comment from command line?

Comment: I cannot check UI, because has no installed VSS (and has no desire to install it :) ), but seems I understand what you talking about... And I do not know answer for your question.